# MYSQL have set a column to not null but still it's accepting null value

Tags: mysql, sql

Structure for a table in mysql5.5

tablename:

```
id:
name:
detail:
```

here even altering the table:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL;
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `name` `name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT NOT NULL;
```

after inserting value:

```
INSERT INTO `databasename`.`tablename` (`id`, `name`, `detail`) VALUES (NULL, '', 'asdfasfdadsfadsfafd');
```

query has run successfully no error row has been added to table,

how can i prevent such empty or null.

regards

Comment: Empty string and `null` values are different, `NOT NULL` constraint will not prevent empty strings. For empty strings you can use `check` constraints like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514178/im-looking-for-a-constraint-to-prevent-the-insert-of-an-empty-string-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename 
MODIFY COLUMN name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL CHECK (name <> '');
```

DEMO:

```
mysql> create table tablename(id int(2) not null, something varchar(25) null, primary key(id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)
mysql> insert into tablename values(0,'hello');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.38 sec)

mysql> insert into tablename values(1,'salut');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.31 sec)

mysql> select * from tablename;
+----+-----------+
| id | something |
+----+-----------+
|  0 | hello     |
|  1 | salut     |
+----+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I run the  `UPDATE` command:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE tablename  MODIFY COLUMN something VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.70 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I insert a *normal* row:

```
mysql> insert into tablename values(2,'france');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.29 sec)
```

But it does not allow me to insert a NULL value:

```
mysql> insert into tablename values(3,NULL);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'something' cannot be null
```

I check to be sure:

```
mysql> select * from tablename;
+----+-----------+
| id | something |
+----+-----------+
|  0 | hello     |
|  1 | salut     |
|  2 | france    |
+----+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: No effect Same result.

Comment: @abas_rafiq I tried the command I gave you on a test table I created. You can see it does its job very well (it can not allow me NULL values insertion). But in your case, I do not understand why. I suggest you to show your MySQL version

Comment: please try (insert into tablename values(3,'');)

Comment: @abas_rafiq NO, you are wrong: `''` is different from  `NULL` because `''` means empty string  so it will accept it of course

Comment: yes on my insert i have explain not null i mean not empty.

Comment: @abas_rafiq in MySQL NOT NULL is not the same as not empty (`''` different from `NULL`) . To do the both things, please check my update