# In MySQL, when I alter a table and add a new attribute with constraint not null, it still accepts null when I use update

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL, I have a table called student as given below,

```
Name       Idnumber
'tony'        1
'jimmy'       2
```

I am going to add one more column using the below query

```
alter table student add location varchar(20) not null;
```

Now, if I use the query,

`update student set location=null where name='tony'`

the value of null is being inserted into the table. Below was the table I got.

```
Name       IdNumber         location
'tony'       1                 null
'jimmy'      2
```

Since I had set location as not null while altering the table, why is it still accepting null? Also, if I tried to insert null using,

```
insert into student(Name,IdNumber) values('robert',3);
```

the query is not demanding a not null value for location. 'Not Null' constraing is only working when I use the query,

```
insert into student (Name,IdNumber,location) values('john',8,null);
```

Please tell my why 'not null' constraint is not working in the other cases described above.

Thanks,
Vivek G

Comment: It is not working because there are already rows on your table. I think mysql in this case ignores that constraint. Not sure though.

Comment: When you create a column it will have null values by default so you can't create a column with a constraint that will be bypassed. Others RDBMs will give you an error about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm looking for a constraint to prevent the insert of an empty string in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514178/im-looking-for-a-constraint-to-prevent-the-insert-of-an-empty-string-in-mysql)