# Does NOT NULL in mysql accept empty string

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.
One with int as primary key and other with a varchar primary key.

When an empty string is inserted ( "" ) i get programming error for int but successfully stores for varchar.
How does this work?

Is there a way to make varchar fields not accept empty strings?
I want them to give some database error which i can catch.

Comment: Because the empty string is not an integer.

Comment: Yes. `varchar` means **Var**iable-length **char**acter data.

Comment: Is there a way to make varchar fields not accept empty strings?

Comment: That is a different question entirely, but typically you validate fields using `trigger`s.

Comment: @shadow0359: Looks like there's already an answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514178/im-looking-for-a-constraint-to-prevent-the-insert-of-an-empty-string-in-mysql

Comment: cool!! didnt know what to search for exactly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty string is not `NULL`, in almost every database and by the ANSI definition.

It so happens that Oracle treats empty strings as `NULL` values, which is generally rather confusing.  But that is an exception to the SQL language.

Answer (score 4):

> When a empty string is inserted ( "" ) i get programming error for int

Because a string is not an `int`.  And there's no way to automatically convert a non-numeric string *to* an `int`.

> but successfully stores for varchar

Because a string *is* a `varchar`.  Columns like [`CHAR` and `VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) are for storing character data, which is what a string is.

None of these values are `NULL`.  `NULL` is the absence of a value.  An empty string is still a value.

Answer (score 1):

An empty string is different from null. (This is true in MySQL and in many programming languages as well.) Try inserting null into the primary key for the varchar. It should fail on the insert - just like the int.

As @David says above, the empty string cannot be converted to an int, and so MySQL chooses null instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, and we need to see the code to know what is the best way to fix this problem, but you can try this:

```
CASE WHEN IN_IntValue = '' THEN NULL ELSE IN_IntValue
```

In general, only Oracle as far as I know look at empty string as NULL. In MySQL they are two different things.